# Hover Over Navigation without including After Content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I currently have a dropdown with pipe dividers like so => Home | About | Tab3

The CSS looks likes so:

```
.navigation li a:after {
 content: " | "; }
```

I use a hover over dropdown menu, but the issue is it includes the | pipe with the top tier dropdown menu when it changes color. The dropdown menu is standard dropdown menu CSS:

```
    .multi-column-dropdown li a {
         display: block;
         clear: both;
         color: #eee;
         white-space: normal;
         font-size: 16px;
       }
```

How do I make it so the hover over selection only includes the actual text without creating a hover over effect over the pipe? It's essentially treating "Home" as "Home |" which I definitely don't want when the background color changes over the hover.

I'm also using Bootstrap 3 for some of the dropdown elements.

Edit: Just to clarify, I know the defacto standard is to add it to the HTML outside the tag. The way bootstrap works and since it is technically a collapsed vertical menu, it pushes the | pipe either above or below the navigation menu rather than staying inline

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just get rid of your | in your css and leave it in your html code?

```
<a href="#">Link 1</a>|
<a href="#">Link 2</a>|
<a href="#">Link 3</a>|
```

Comment: No, when I add it to the HTML, it pushes the | pipe element below the actual navigation menu. It doesn't actually end up staying inline with the rest of the other elements

Comment: Just to clarify: even when its inside of the CSS navigation tags?

Comment: It stays inline when it is inside of the tag, but when its outside (</a> |) it bumps it out of the navigation. But then it styles it when its inline inside the tag

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding this right, your saying that the '|' is being styled by your hover style?

you can target this like so;

```
.multi-column-dropdown li a:hover:before {
    //Put your css here
    color: black;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

your issue is about inherit because the **:after class pseudo** is the content of its parent.you can style the **:after** to ensure what you want style.
[There is a link.](http://jsbin.com/dagova/1/edit?html,css,output)